# Export on .xlsxm file

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

In my WinApp I export data to a specific tab of an Excel spreadsheet, in which there are macros (file extension .xlxm).

In this workbook, the data is always inserted from the same cell when it is empty, but it can happen that has already had the previous entries, so you have to retrieve the first available blank cell on the new line after the one that has already had the data inserted. The sequence of entries in the cells is similar to the following: in cells A1: A3, and then such as A10: A15, dropping the cells A4 to A9 because they are cells with formulas. I would to add that I must to control every cell of workbook for to fill in data from winApp. I hope to be able to explain the scenario.

Comment: Are you doing this using interop or one of the openxml libraries? Can you post what you have done so far?

Comment: thanks for reply. I'm starting from zero. I don't have any idea. My scope is to fill in some data in Excel workbook cells from database. I'm looking for any help of to make this. May you give me some reference please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a library such as [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) from NuGet to achieve this. Something like this would do the trick.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<string> ExampleData = new List<string> { "my", "intestesting", "data" };

        using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(@"C:\Temp\example.xlsm")))
        {
            ExcelWorksheet ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets["MySheet"];
            int lastRowIndex = ws.Dimension.End.Row;
            int idx = lastRowIndex + 1;

            foreach (var datum in ExampleData)
            {
                ws.Cells[idx, 1].Value = datum;
                idx++;
            }

            package.Save();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Very interesting!! what do you think about about NPOI library?

Comment: I have no experience with NPOI. I tend to use EPPlus but haven't spent much time with the alternatives (EPPlus has always served my needs)